# IDA Pro: Reverse-Engineering Temp Storage

Tags: storage, reverse-engineering, temporary, unpack, ida

In the executable I am reverse-engineering, there are several references to a path in my `D:\ drive`. However, I do not have a `D:\ drive` connected. Is it possible that it creates a temporary storage site *in* the executable?

For example, there is a string:

```
D:\BuildAgent\...\bin\...\fileIWantToSee.jpg
```

IDA even believes that the symbol information is in the D drive, and attempts to look for it, to no avail. There are many instances of file references within these strings, and many of them end with a:

```
Line: **LINENUMBER**
```

Where would I go about trying to find where this storage is located? Thank you!

EDIT: Could it be in a specific section?

Comment: It could also be that these are references to paths *on the developer's machine* (not in use, just for debug purposes), especially if they are in the executable and not in runtime-generated memory. If we are indeed talking about runtime-set paths, and it is a simulated storage like suggested in the answer from Eugene, then you could either just scan the memory for strings which occur in JPEG files (for example they often contain `JFIF` or `Exif`, start with bytes `FF D8` and end with bytes `FF D9`), or you could write a DLL which calls GetOpenFileName and exports any selected file using [...]

Comment: [...] your own code to write the contents to another file outside that path, and inject the DLL into the process. Assuming it's a system like Eugene said, this should allow you to "copy" the file outside of the hidden area.

Comment: Actually, now that I read your question again, it is most likely that these are part of assertions which contain the file path _of the source file on the program author's machine, not yours_ and line number of the line of code in which the assertion is done. So there is no way for you to get to those files, they don't exist on your computer at all. Say, is the file extension of the file in question really `.jpg`? Or maybe something like `.pas` or `.cpp`? This would support my theory.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible that it creates a temporary storage site in the executable?

This is possible. There exists at least one product (http://www.boxedapp.com/, kind of our competitor :) that lets the application create such container -- the calls to file APIs are intercepted by the code added to the application by this product, and this added code handles specific paths in a different way (emulating file operations), letting all other calls go to Windows API.